# Como colocar linha a dividir items num Spinner?

Tags: android

Estou a tentar colocar uma linha a dividir os items que tenho num `Spinner` mas não consigo que me apareça.

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_default"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

**spinner_dropbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"/>

<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#808080</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity**
(...)

```
 //adapter creation categorias
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, list_categorias);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropbox);
        categoria.setAdapter(adapter);
```

O que estou a obter é isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém consegue ajudar? 
Porque não desenha a linha entre os diversos items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que deve fazer é aplicar o *style*

```
<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#808080</item>
</style>
```

ao `android:dropDownListViewStyle` do *theme* da aplicação em vez de atribuí-lo como *style* do `CheckedTextView` .

Acrescente esta linha ao *style* do *theme* da aplicação:

```
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
```

Comment: Não consigo perceber a resposta. No styles.xml eu tenho definido o spinnerDropDownItemStyle que depois é associado ao spinner_dropbox. Este spinner_dropbox é posteriormente chamado no java.

Comment: O style não deve ser associado ao spinner_dropbox mas sim no style do theme da aplicação.

Comment: Obrigada! Ja funcionou.